# PureFTPd - is it possible to limit file access for virtual users?

Tags: ftp, filesystems

I have a website for a little group of people, where each of them can login using their username and password. Since we'd like to share some files, I am looking for a FTP server, which would allow logins and access limitations for single users and groups of users loaded from the database of the website.

PureFTPd supports loading user IDs and group IDs using SQL (MySQL in this case). But I don't understand how am I supposed to connect "physical" files (stored directly on the filesystem) with their owners in the database.

There should be a folder for all the user files somewhere in the filesystem (e. g.: /ftp), where they should be stored. No matter if they will be in further directories or all together, people should be able to access only files that are owned by them or by a group they are in. Everything should happen on a linux, but a platform-independent solution would be greatly appreciated.

How would you approach this situation? Is it possible with PureFTPd? If not, what else FTP server would you suggest?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes PureFTPD will limit acces of each user to it's own folder by chrooting everyone. See this tutorial http://www.debiantutorials.com/pure-ftpd-with-mysql-backend/